# Renaming multiple files removing parentheses along with everyghing in them

Tags: file, debian, rename

I am looking for a way to rename multiple files with different extensions removing everything between parentheses.

example

```
foo(foo bar).bar > foo.bar
foo/bar/foo(foo bar).bar > foo/foo.bar
foo/bar/foo(foo bar).bar > foo/bar/foo.bar
```

I came up with this from another question:

```
rename -v 's/ \(.*\)\./\./' ./*.*
```

But I don't think rename is what I need. I read the man and it doesn't seem to have a recurse flag. Is there an easier way to do this.

Comment: This question is probably more fit for [unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Anyway, I guess that by *-r flag* you mean to recurse into subdirectories. Also note that pattern won't match your examples because it has a space before the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the command you provided and `find` to look for files recursively:

```
find . -type f -exec rename -v 's/\(.*\)\./\./' {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to work. I believe my original string leaves an empty space before the extension, but I figured out how to remove it. Thanks again.